# TFSSecurity execution issue

Tags: tfs, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create member group within project in TFS using command line tool. Unfortunately for some reason I'm keep getting error connected with scope parameter.

```
TFSSecurity.exe /gc "http://mytfshost:8080/tfs/collectionName/Some Project Name" "Group Name" /collection:http://mytfshost:8080/tfs/collectionNam
```

Error contains such information:

> Error: TF50620: The Team Foundation identity scope http://mytfshost:8080/tfs/collectionName/Some Project Name does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the internal project URI for the project; you cannot simply append the project name to the public collection URI.  This will be something with a `vstfs://` scheme and have the project GUID at the end.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400774.aspx):

> To obtain the URI for a team project, open Team Explorer, right-click the team project, click Properties, and copy the entire value of the URL property.

Comment: See http://roadtoalm.com/2014/07/28/add-permissions-with-tfssecuritythe-ultimate-reference/ for a synopsis of possible values and how to get them.